# REGEXP_REPLACE and REGEXP_EXTRACT

Tags: regexp-replace

I have a URI column coming in a log. I have to parse it and remove the certain parts from it and store it in a table. For Example if I have `/v7/cp/members/~PERF1SP826T90869AN/options`, then I have to store it as `/v7/cp/members/*/options`. Can I do that using REGEXP_REPLACE?

Also I would like to see if I could store that part that I removed from the URI as another column?
For Example from `/v7/cp/members/~PERF1SP826T90869AN/options`, I should store `/v7/cp/members/*/options` as a column and `PERF1SP826T90869AN` in a separate column.

Comment: You might increase the chance of an answer if you add a tag for the database engine you're using.

Comment: In short, yes but is it in a log table or log file?  What program, OS, tool will you be using as not all regex engines are created equal. Look at it as a delimited string where the delimiter is a slash and where you want to replace the 4th element with a `'*'` and also store it.  The real question is, is it always the 4th element?  If not, what are the rules for finding it?  Between elements containing "members" and "options"? Always starts with a tilda?  Need more info to build a robust regex that won't return false positives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Oracle, here's a method:

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
      select '/v7/cp/members/~PERF1SP826T90869AN/options' from dual
    )
    select regexp_replace(str, '(.*?)(/|$)', '*/', 1, 5)   as replaced,
           regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(/|$)', 1, 5, NULL, 1) as fifth_element
    from tbl;

REPLACED                 FIFTH_ELEMENT
------------------------ -------------------
/v7/cp/members/*/options ~PERF1SP826T90869AN

SQL>
```